# std::initializer_list value as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, initializer-list

I am trying to do something like this:

```
template<typename enumType,
         std::initializer_list<enumType> values,
         std::initializer_list<std::string> mappings>
struct enum_converter {
    enumType toEnum(const std::string& literal) { ... }
    std::string toString(const enumType value) { ... }
};
```

I want to use it as follows:

```
enum test_enum {value_a, value_b};
struct test_enum_converter : public enum_converter<
        test_enum,
        {value_a, value_b},
        {"a", "b"}> {};
```

GCC tells me:

```
class std::initializer_list<_Tp> is not a valid type
for a template constant parameter.
```

Adding `const` to the type does not change anything. Is there a workaround or a similar solution?

Comment: You definitely can't have strings as template arguments, though const char pointers would work.

Comment: If Im not wrong, const char only works if it is declared global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only integral types, enumerations, pointers and references are allowed as non-type template parameters. `std::initializer_list` is neither of those.

Do you need the values & mappings to be template parameters? How about making them normal parameters of the constructor, and keeping only the enum as a template param?

```
template<typename enumType>
struct enum_converter {
    enum_converter(std::initializer_list<enumType> values, std::initializer_list<std::string> mappings) : values(values), mappings(mappings)

    enumType toEnum(const std::string& literal) { ... }
    std::string toString(const enumType value) { ... }

private:
    std::initializer_list<enumType> values;
    std::initializer_list<std::string> mappings;
};

enum_converter<test_enum> test_enum_converter({...}, {...});

int main()
{
    test_enum_converter.toEnum("bla");
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is an instance-free alternative:

```
template<typename enumType>
struct enum_converter {
    static init(std::initializer_list<enumType> values, std::initializer_list<std::string> mappings)
    { s_values = values; s_mappings = mappings; }

    static enumType toEnum(const std::string& literal) { ... }
    static std::string toString(const enumType value) { ... }

private:
    static std::initializer_list<enumType> s_values;
    static std::initializer_list<std::string> s_mappings;
};
```

Just call `init()` once before using the class.

If you need more than one instantiation for a particular enumeration, you can add a disambiguation parameter to the template, like this:

```
template <typename enumType, typename tag>
struct enum_converter { /*as before*/ };

int main()
{
  struct data_strings;
  struct user_readable_strings;
  enum_converter<test_enum, data_strings>::init({...}, {"a", "b"});
  enum_converter<test_enum, user_readable_strings>::init({...}, {"Option A", "Option B"});
}
```

Comment: Yes, they need to be template parameters. In the actual code, `test_enum_converter` is a type converter for the SOCI library, which uses static methods for converting.

Comment: @flyx I've added an instance-free version.

Comment: The major thing I don't like about this solution is that it separates the type declaration from the mapping specification. From an idealistic point of view, it would be better for the mapping list to be inserted at compile-time. However, this version is much more readable than what Kerrek suggested, so I'll go with it and add some asserts to the methods to make sure init is called exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers can only be template arguments if they are constant expressions, i.e. the address of an object with extern linkage. The following code works, though it's your call whether it's worth it:

```
typedef char const * charptype;

template <int, charptype> struct item;

template <typename ...> struct econv
{
  static constexpr charptype convert(int) { return nullptr; }
};

template <int I, charptype S, typename ...Tail>
struct econv<item<I, S>, Tail...>
{
  static constexpr charptype convert(int i)
  {
    return i == I ? S : econv<Tail...>::convert(i);
  }
};

#include <iostream>
extern char const Hello[] = "Hello";
extern char const World[] = "World";

int main()
{
    std::cout << econv< item<1, Hello>
                      , item<2, World> >::convert(2)
    << "\n";
}
```

By putting the strings into an anonymous namespace and using some helper macros, this approach might be cleaned up a bit to look presentable.